# My React Native app crashes during Login and Logout ( when context is changed )

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I have a react native app and whenever I try to login or logout the app crashes .. I am not getting any error logs in React Native Debugger.

so the App Crashes and then when I reopen the app the changes have already taken effect ( i.e :- If I was trying to login I would be logged in when I reopen the app)

I have 2 files for Navigation

CofficNavigator.tsx

```
// This file has all the routing
// here BottomNavigator is a tab Navigator and AuthNavigator is a stack navigator
// Before the app crashing all the correct state is set but it just crashes

// ----------- Final Stack Navigator ----------------
const FinalStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
export const FinalNavigator = (props: any) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState<boolean | null>(
    authContext.isLoggedIn
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (authContext.isLoggedIn !== signedIn && !authContext.isLoading) {
      setSignedIn(authContext.isLoggedIn);
    }
  }, [authContext]);

  return (
    <FinalStackNavigator.Navigator>
      {signedIn ? (
        <>
          <FinalStackNavigator.Screen
            name="BottomNavigator"
            component={BottomNavigator}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <FinalStackNavigator.Screen
            name="AuthNavigator"
            component={AuthNavigator}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </FinalStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

AppNavigator.tsx

```
export const AppNavigator = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <FinalNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

*-------- Login Logic flow -------------*
on success of login API I call this line

```
await authContext.changeCofficToken(result.data.login.token);
```

**AuthContext.ts**

```
const changeCofficToken = async (token: string) => {
    await setItem("cofficToken", token);
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    setCofficToken(token);
  };
```

**helper.ts**

```
export const setItem = async (key: string, value: any) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <FilterContextProvider>
        <SearchTermContextProvider>
          <ShowVerticalListContextProvider>
            <CouponContextProvider>
              <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <AppNavigator />
              </ApolloProvider>
            </CouponContextProvider>
          </ShowVerticalListContextProvider>
        </SearchTermContextProvider>
      </FilterContextProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
```

*------ End of Login Logic code flow -------*

Error logs from my IOS Simulator

```
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.957FA264-501C-44C3-80F3-9E8D1F600A1E[15500] (UIKitApplication:host.exp.Exponent[e036][rb-legacy][15601]): Service exited due to SIGABRT
assertion failed: 19F101 17F61: libxpc.dylib + 83746 [ED46009E-B942-37CC-95D4-82CF3FE90BD8]: 0x7d
```

**Please Note** :- I am using Expo if it matters

**Video Link** :- https://fisico-dhaval.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screen+Recording+2020-08-20+at+5.38.06+PM.mov

If you need any other code snippets then please do lemme know

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: are you sure the problem is in the navigation and not in the code used to perform the login? Because your code seems correct to me

Comment: I am getting the correct context values and it works fine before the return and then it breaks.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of error?

Comment: I actually am not getting any errors in the console .. it just crashes .. where will I be able to get the errors?

Comment: During the crash, what is the output logs from adb logcat? Your crash might come from something in the native part. You can open Android Studio to inspect the native logs

Comment: I have added some logs from the Simulator debugger in the question

Comment: Have you checked logs by enabling debug-mode in `dev settings`?

Comment: I did enable debug mode in dev settings of my simulators and it just does not show these errors so I pulled logs from Simulator debug and those are the ones I added in the question and I did attach a debugger too but its not too helpful either .. just to add I am using Expo it it matters at all

Comment: https://fisico-dhaval.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Screen+Recording+2020-08-20+at+5.38.06+PM.mov is the screen recording link for the issue

Comment: Can you confirm, is your token in `changeCofficToken` function is not undefined or null

Comment: It is defined and it works and actually the data is changing and It works and I am assuming even if it didn't this error should be visible in js logs before the crash

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was only happening on iOS while changing the context value. How I resolve this was by applying the context value inside the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code where you setSignin. In case if you are saving and clearing token, make sure those libraries are supported and linked properly.

Comment: I have added Login Logic code to the question .. if you need anything else then do lemme know

Answer (score 0):

Service exited due to SIGABRT is a common issue in Native iOS development, it can be cause due to various events. While working on react-native, I have never experienced this error. But I'm adding some of my observation, may be that can help you,

1. This can be cause due to some buggy component, which are not compatible with Expo version. So, you need to add many `console.log` or may be comment some things and check is there any functionality or a component causing this error. A buggy component can be a culprit.
2. If you have pod installed, Make sure you check all your libraries.You likely have some issue with an installed external library. and make sure you run pod install and delete node_modules folder and then run npm install again (close the packager too)
3. You can also use `sentry` or any other crash reporting library to detect crashes, It will give you the exact line number.
4. Sometimes the crash reporting libraries won't work, the reason can be that the crash occurs before the js bundle is loaded and because of that, the library is not yet initialised and it can't detect the crash. If so you can install a native crash reporting library, You can use fabric for that, or even bugsnag.

These are few scenarios, I've observed via which you can debug or detect what's the real cause of this error.